# Xaml strange behavior: textbox changed flowdirection

Tags: xaml, textbox

I have a question - I have a textbox in my application. From one minute to the other, it changed its flow direction from leftToRigt into rightToLeft. 
Of course I checked it's style and everything (because all other textboxes, even those inheriting the same style, do behave in their normal way.

I seriously can't explain it to myself - is there anything I can do to make it behave normally again? I tried setting the flow direction explicitly but nothing changed.... unfortunately I can't find any answers on the net...

**UPDATE**
My XAML looks like this:

```
                    <TextBox x:Name="m_tbMaschine" 
                     Margin="0 15 10 15" Grid.Row="2"
                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Maschine" 
                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HintOpacity=".3"
                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                     Text="{Binding Path=AktuelleMaschine.MaschineBezeichnung, 
                                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                        IsAsync=True}"
                     Style="{DynamicResource tboxHintBase}" 
                     IsEnabled="{Binding Editierbar, IsAsync=True}" />
```

and the style it is based on:

```
    <Style x:Key="tboxHintBase" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}">
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HintOpacity" Value=".8"/>
    </Style>
```

Cheers Veronica

Comment: Do you have any CultureInfo stuff set or getting toggled?

Comment: The cultural info is set to German... unless I changed it for that particular textbox by some shortcut accidentally... but I would see that in the xaml file, no?

Comment: No you're right, you likely would. Unless maybe there's a custom style being used with an unwanted trigger for FlowDirection or something then I'm stumped without seeing more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, though I don't understand how it could cause such a kind of behavior... maybe somebody can explain?

```
 Text="{Binding Path=AktuelleMaschine.MaschineBezeichnung, 
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                    IsAsync=True}"
```

Removing the IsAsync property changed the textbox's behavior back to its original state :)